# opening site directly by entering domain name

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, dns

hey guys, recently i uploaded one of my clients site online, now what his requirement is the site should also be opened even user just enter domain name, without www and .com, is there any settings in the iis which can make it possible to do this..

Please reply with some suggestion.

Comment: no. you have to type .com. u can use Alt+Enter for that from client browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the binding to that website. This example will open the website if he types `site` on the address bar.

[image: change the bindings]

But only if site redirects to the server, this can be done in the `hosts` file located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`. Adding this line

```
// server address        name
127.0.0.1                site
```

This **will only work on a machine that modifies the hosts file**. You can't have a registered domain without a suffix.

AND

As pointed by @Govind

> it will work on local system only dear
>   before sending request to location
>   host name find IP on DNS Database

Comment: thats good trick but not the real answer. **You can't have a registered domain without a suffix** should be you can't open site without using suffix... :-)

Comment: @Bruno: i tried as you same, directly on the server, but the it does not work, in IE or chrome, but it works in FF, even if i dont modify the file which you specified, can you suggest me what could be the reason. can you also tell me what you mean by saying you cant have registered domain without a suffix

Comment: @Abbas firefox implicitly add www. prefix and .com suffix if u dont provide so it is working in firefox. this trick working on ur client not on server.....

Comment: so, the moral of the story is it is not possible to implement something like this

Comment: @Abbas Idk, maybe it is cache? I've just tested on Chrome and it worked. Try to: `run > cmd > ipconfig /flushdns` then try to open `http://site/` (with `http://`). It has to work...

Comment: assume suffix check on DNS Database and then redirect to appropriate location...... abc may be abc.com or abc.in or abc.co.uk which will be consider...

Comment: @BrunoLM.. it will work on local system only dear before sending request to location host name find IP on DNS Database

Comment: @Bruno: can you rectify me if i am wrong. under c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc opened the hosts file, edited the last line as #209.59.186.108   rwonline.

also added the binding in the site. and added the sitename as rwonline.
are the steps proper... am i missing anything, coz even in the chrome, site is not getting opened, by rwonline, can you please suggest

Comment: @Abbas if you are accessing the website from a remote place it will not work as pointed by @Govind. It will only work with you are running the website on the same network. Firefox is automatically adding `www` and `com` suffix as also pointed by @Govind. So to access remotely it is not possible.